# Skip numeration figure and table caption

Tags: latex, figure, tex, caption

How to make a table and figure caption without  any automatic numeration?

For example:

```
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
    \textbf{Name} & \textbf{Description} \\
        Foo & bar \\
        Foo & bar
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Nice Table a.I.3. Number of table passed in caption, so it don''t need any automatic numeration }
    \label{tab:table}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Try http://tex.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `caption` package (http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/caption/)

It defines the `\caption*` command for the table environment.